# Changing the template arguments of derived classes

Tags: c++, generic-programming, boost-mpl

In the code below, C's base class B1's template argument OFFSET depends on B0, and B2 on B1.

This is done by manual write the code every time an instance of C is created (in the main method). Is there a way to move this functionality to the definition of C instead?

```
template<int OFFSET>
struct A {
    enum O { offset = OFFSET };
    enum S { size = 2 };
};

template<int OFFSET>
struct B {
    enum O { offset = OFFSET };
    enum S { size = 4 };
};

template < typename B0, typename B1, typename B2 >
struct C : public B0, B1, B2 {
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // instance of C
    C< A<1>,

       B< A<1>::offset * A<1>::size >,

       A<
           B< A<1>::offset * A<1>::size >::offset *
           B< A<1>::offset * A<1>::size >::size
       >
    > c1;

    // does the same thing
    C< A<1>,

       B< A<1>::size >,

       A<
           A<1>::size *
           B< A<1>::size >::size
       >
    > c2;

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To answer the comments, here are the steps I think needs to be taken to solve this:

- Write a metafunction which can change the offset:
  set_new_offset which for T defines the type T<2>
- Use boost::mpl::times to calculate the new offsets
- Add more template magic...

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarkB it is a long story, but part of the real problem is to learn metaprogramming in c++.

Comment: It does seem like you're trying to solve a problem in an unusual way.  You're inheriting from three `struct`s only to gain access to 3 `OFFSET` and 3 `SIZE` enums.  And the second and third can be calculated in terms of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with template templates in C, although I'm not 100% sold it's an improvement. If you only ever need three bases this should be fine. If you need an arbitrary number of bases...there must be a better way to do this than inheritance as this method will get unwieldy.

```
template<int OFFSET>
struct A {
    enum O { offset = OFFSET };
    enum S { size = 2 };
};

template<int OFFSET>
struct B {
    enum O { offset = OFFSET };
    enum S { size = 4 };
};

template < typename B0, template <int T> class B1, template <int T> class B2 >
struct C : public B0, B1<B0::offset * B0::size>, B2<B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::offset * B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::size> {
    enum
    {
        B0_offset = B0::offset,
        B1_offset = B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::offset,
        B2_offset = B2<B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::offset * B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::size>::offset,
        B0_size = B0::size,
        B1_size = B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::size,
        B2_size = B2<B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::offset * B1<B0::offset * B0::size>::size>::size
    };
};

int main()
{
    // instance of C
    C< A<1>,

       B,

       A
    > c1;

    static_cast<void>(c1);

    // does the same thing
    C< A<1>,

       B,

       A
    > c2;

    static_cast<void>(c2);

    std::cout << c1.B0_offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << c1.B1_offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << c1.B2_offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << c1.B0_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << c1.B1_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << c1.B2_size << std::endl;

    std::cout << c2.B0_offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << c2.B1_offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << c2.B2_offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << c2.B0_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << c2.B1_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << c2.B2_size << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did not know about template template arguments before, smart... In the current implementation I need this for 32 arguments so I hope for a further improvements...

Comment: @Allan If you need 32 templates arguments, I'm 99% sure you're doing something sub-optimally.

Comment: I sure am, but the project I'm working on has still not switched to c++0x

Comment: Some preprocessor code makes it actually look okay: `#define B0_ B0<1>`, `#define B1_ B1<B0_::offset * B0_::size>`, `#define B2_ B2<B1_::offset * B1_::size>`

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a helper class:

```
template <template <int> class C, int N>
struct Composer
{
    enum O { offset = C<N>::offset * C<N>::size; };
    enum S { size = C<N>::size; };
};
```

Then you can say:

```
C<A<1>, Composer<A, 1>, Composer<B, Composer<A, 1>::offset> c2;
```

If necessary one could think up a higher-order composer that allows you to form higher "powers" of composition.

(Maybe `Composer` should have been called `Bind1st` or so...)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your solution. Have you noticed that A and B are different? (size=2 and size=4). The code you have suggested C will derive from Composer, not from A and B? How would that work for more complex version of A and B? (and version where A and B are more different?)

Comment: @Allan: Sorry, the size was indeed an error. I think it's fixed now.